# React missing in Product (Edit Scheme) after react-native upgrad

Tags: react-native

After upgrade to latest react-native Product -> Edit scheme is missing in Xcode.

My Podfile is like below

```
#Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

target 'Helloworld' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Helloworld

  target 'Helloworld-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

  target 'HelloworldTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Try with delete PODS and podlock file and install pod again.

Comment: Shall I need to delete podfile. Removed Pods and podfile.lock

Comment: No, don't delete podfile

Comment: Are you able to work now?

Comment: I am getting  Unable to find a specification for `React-Core` depended upon by `rn-fetch-blob`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: I have checkout all changes Which i previously made in my Podfile. And then run podintall.

Comment: No. After check out the Podfile, I have lot of packages alreay in Podfile. Shall I need to remove manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203001/discussion-between-brijesh-shiroya-and-sejn).

Comment: Now I am getting Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening App.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: I have a general question about a huge file generated after upgrade.

After react-native upgrade I found huge files like ios/Index/Datasource/some thing....

What is the use of this files. Shall I need to commit this or need to move in .gitignore.

Can you explain why it get generated?